# Creating a transparent canvas with GD

Tags: php, gd

I am trying to create a *transparent* image canvas and then place other random images on top of this canvas. I then finally save the final image as a `gif`. I have tried the below:

```
    $canvas = imagecreatetruecolor($this->canvas_width, $this->canvas_height);
    imagesavealpha($canvas, true);
    imagealphablending($canvas, false);       

    $trans_colour = imagecolorallocatealpha($canvas, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($canvas, 0, 0, $trans_colour);
```

However, if there is some unused space left on the canvas then this part is black. I thought this area should be transparent?

Am I applying transparency correctly with the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`imagesavealpha` can not be used for images you eventually intend to save as GIF because GIF images do not have alpha channels. From the docs:

> **imagesavealpha** — Set the flag to save full alpha channel
>   information (as opposed to single-color transparency) when saving PNG
>   images

So it only works if you are going to save the image as PNG. GIF images can do transparency, but not with an alpha channel; they can only be "transparent" or "not transparent" by defining a particular color as transparent. In PHP you can do that using [imagecolortransparent](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php). For example, to make all black transparent, you could do:

```
$black_color = imagecolorallocate($canvas, 0, 0, 0);
imagecolortransparent($canvas, $black_color);
```

Comment: Thanks Ben! I understand. Now I am going to have to come with a color that is unlikely going to be used. Because I am guessing if I place an image that has some black in it, it will be made transparent? Anyone know the most unused color in RGB format!

Comment: @Abs, high-intensity blue or green! http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroma_key; "Blue and green are used because they are the colors least like skin tone"

Comment: @Abs This question was already asked http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20110123172050AA8E0G1 ;)

Comment: (Of course, use a color that depends on you task. For people, blue and green are good transparency choices for skin tones. For your task, it may be different).